# How to reuse Stack Allocator in RapidJSON without reallocating memory

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I'm running a single-threaded system in FreeRTOS with limited resources.

I already preallocate buffers for the RapidJSON allocators as so:

```
char            valueBuffer[2048];
char            parseBuffer[1024];
rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<FreeRTOSRapidJSONAllocator> valueAllocator (valueBuffer, sizeof(valueBuffer))
rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<FreeRTOSRapidJSONAllocator> parseAllocator (parseBuffer, sizeof(parseBuffer));
```

The issue I have is that every time one of the allocators is used, its size keeps on increasing (and allocating new memory if necessary) unless they are cleared. The problem with calling `Clear()` on the allocators is that `Malloc` is called again when the allocators are next resized, which I want to avoid.

Is there a way to simply reuse the existing preallocated memory, such as by setting the allocators' size back to zero, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a custom allocator. Essentially a copy of `rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator` with the addition of the following method:

```
void Reset()
{
    chunkHead_->size = 0;
    chunkHead_->next = 0;
}
```

Which should be called every time you're done with the last string that was parsed.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do the same, and thought I'd note what from reading the allocator code seems to be an alternative:

While I again create a char buffer[2048], I do not create and keep an allocator alongside it.

Rather, I create and delete an allocator anew when needed, while re-using the memory block. From reading the code of the allocator I see no Malloc so that should all be on the stack, no?

Edit - code example:

```
class MyClass
{
public: 
    myClass() : 
    _json_log_string_buffer(&_json_string_buffer_allocator, 
                            _json_buffer_size) {}

(...)
private:
    static constexpr int _json_buffer_size {4096};
    char _json_logger_buffer[_json_buffer_size];

    rapidjson::CrtAllocator _json_string_buffer_allocator;
    rapidjson::StringBuffer _json_log_string_buffer;
};

MyClass::log_to_json()
{
    rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> 
    json_logger_allocator {_json_logger_buffer, 
                           sizeof(_json_logger_buffer)};

    rapidjson::Document json_doc(&json_logger_allocator);

    auto& allocator = json_doc.GetAllocator();

    json_doc.SetObject();

    // using it:
    json_doc.AddMember("id", id(), allocator);
    json_doc.AddMember("KEY", "VALUE", 
    allocator);
    (...)

    // Here, monitoring the size of allocator, it never goes 
    // beyond the 4096 on repeat invocations.
    // If I had it as a member, only creating once, it would grow.
    std::cout << "JSON allocator size: " << allocator.Size() << 
    ", capacity: " << allocator.Capacity() << std::endl;


    // Bonus point: I'm also using a rapidjson::StringBuffer.
    // From a first read it doesn't seem to re-allocate.
    // It doesn't use a MemoryPoolAllocator so I cannot do the 
    // same for it as I did for rapidjson::Document.
    _json_log_string_buffer.Clear();

    rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> 
    writer(_json_log_string_buffer);

    json_doc.Accept(writer);
    auto as_string = _json_log_string_buffer.GetString();

    // Using string with logger...
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your response and show some code?

Comment: @CigogneEveillée Sure thing, I've edited it now with a simplified example of my real code, to illustrate.